# Java class import issues. import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Float not working

Tags: java, import, processing

I am using the java.awt.geom library in Processing and specifically using the Rectangle2D.Float class.

When I use `import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Float` I get an error when I try declaring `Rectangle2D.Float buttonOne;`, but if I use `import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D` or `import java.awt.geom.*` the code works fine.

I am wondering why this is.

Comment: Could you provide a runnable source code so we can help you ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just drop the Rectangle2D from the Float it will work with the first import

Comment: OP already knows that. *but if I use import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D or import java.awt.geom.\* the code works fine.*

Comment: @BackSlash the OP does not seem to realize that `Rectangle2D.Float bO;` needs the import of `Rectangle2D` rather than `Float`. Static import might have been shown, or maybe better not.

Comment: Yes, because you then just import the Rectangle2D class and then you can access the Rectangle2D.Float, if you don't do that and import just java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Float then it is not clear what Rectangle2D.Float buttonOne; because the Compiler does not know what the Rectangle2D class is.

Comment: @JoopEggen From question: `When I use import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Float I get an error when I try declaring Rectangle2D.Float buttonOne;, but if I use import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D or import java.awt.geom.* the code works fine.` - In my understanding he is just asking why it works with `Rectangle2D` but doesn't with `Rectangle2D.Float`, and this answer doesn't answer that question.

Comment: @BackSlash yes the formulation is tricky. And I take your critic as constructive for the answer (a better formulation). Bye.

Comment: @BackSlash That is exactly the question. I just want to know why one works and the other doesn't. It's not something I had ever come across previously.